# Calculate the length of a string in pixels in openCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, drawing, size

Does anybody know any functions that `openCV` has or any methods to get the length of a string in pixels?

For example, I have

> string c = "Hello"

and I use it to draw to an image by `cvPutText`. How can I get the numbers of pixels of that string in that image the string occupied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [getTextSize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#gettextsize).

Comment: Well, then you're supposed to select this as the answer to reward me :-)